# Why this strange behavior in google chrome and IE?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-chrome, fpdf, save-as

I am using `fpdf` library and generating pdfs... What happens when i click `ExportToPdf` button in firefox it opens the `Save as` dialogbox but google chrome and IE just opens the pdf file in browser, the `save as` doesn't seem to open it... Why this strange behavior?

Comment: Firefox is the oddity in this respect, most browsers made in the last 3 years or so will actually open it inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the content-disposition response header to control this behaviour - if value is inline then pdf will open inside the browser, attachment will show save as dialog box.